# why "%c%c",92,110 in printf("%c%c",92,110) doesn't acts as escape sequence?

Tags: c, char, escaping, ascii

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(){
printf("Hello%c%cWorld",92,110);/*92 is ASCII value of \ and 110 is ASCII value of n*/
getch();
}
```

Output of above program is Hello\nWorld.

Comment: You print \, then you print `n`.  How is this incorrect or unexpected?

Comment: \n does not act as escape sequence

Comment: And so you know, @CJKoirala, it is the C preprocessor, cpp, that converts `\n` to a newline character.  `printf` and C compilers in general know nothing about `\n` or other sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpretation of escape sequence happens in translation phase whereas, in your code, the sequence only *appears* at runtime.

Moreover, the newline, `\n` is not a *combination* of two separate `char` literals `\` and `n`, it is a single value, denoted ny `\n`.

See the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), a newline has ASCII value of 10.

Answer (score 1):

The '\n' escape sequence is interpreted by the C compiler and changed into a new line character.  That doesn't mean that an '\n' sequence is automatically turned into a newline character.  Something has to be expecting to interpret it.

Compare this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("Hello%c%cWorld",92,110);
}
```

Which outputs `Hello\nWorld` (literally)

With this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("Hello%cWorld",10);
}
```

Which outputs

`Hello
World`

With an actual newline character (`\012` in octal, `10` in decimal, or `0x0a` in hex)

Answer (score 0):

ASCII for \n is 10 not '\' plus 'n' try the following code,you can get what you want:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(){
    printf("Hello%cWorld\n",10);
    printf("\\nis%d",'\n');
    getch();
}
```